# Potential Impact of Violating ZwOpenKey Should Only Be Called at IRQL = PASSIVE_LEVEL

Tags: driver, windbg, wdk

A 3rd party data loss prevention driver when enabled driver verifier on it causes driver verifier bugcheck based on [IrqlZwPassive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff547897(v=VS.85).aspx) Rule

The crash includes the following information:

[ZwOpenKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567014(v=vs.85).aspx) should only be called at IRQL = PASSIVE_LEVEL.

What are some of the potential impacts to a Windows system if ZwOpenKey is used outside of IRQL=PASSIVE_LEVEL?

Is this always a serious problem that we should raise with a vendor, or only in certain scenarios.

Comment: Since you don't own the source code, I would say this is not a programming related question but a more general PC driver issue to be asked at SuperUser.com

Comment: It's always a serious problem.

Answer (score 1):

all Zw api in kernel must be called only on `PASSIVE_LEVEL`. this is by design. if call it on `APC_LEVEL` this already will be *UB* some times this can work, some times produce hang or crash. say in case `ZwOpenKey` - registry manager can read key data from disk, if it still not in memory. so pass IRP to filesystem and wait for it complete. but Irp for completion can insert special APC (`IopCompleteRequest`) in calling thread. if thread on APC level - APC will not be executed, until IRQL of thread not lower to passive. but it never done - he wait on IRP complete..

another point - on exit from Zw service, system check - are `UserApcPending` in Thread and if yes, raise IRQL to `APC_LEVEL`, initiate user apc, and lower it back to `PASSIVE_LEVEL` (system assume that Zw called on `PASSIVE_LEVEL`) - so you can enter to Zw api at `APC_LEVEL` and exit on `PASSIVE_LEVEL`. can ask - why thread at some time have `APC_LEVEL` ? simply, because nothing to do IRQL raised ? or exist some requirements why at some point must be `APC_LEVEL` ? if yes, what is be if situation require stay on `APC_LEVEL` but thread ahead of time lower IRQL to `PASSIVE_LEVEL` ? really UB. in most case can be nothing. but in some case can be very nasty bug which very hard catch and research.